# Rails json response in emberjs

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js

This is my serializer

```
class TestSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :post
    def post
        @post = user.joins(:post).select("user.name as name,post.content as content").where("user_id = ?",object.id)
    end

end
```

How can i call this json response in emberjs model and in view.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have this a little backwards. If you want to serialize a Post, you should have a PostSerializer.

If you already have a Post model setup like the following,

```
class User < AR::Base
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < AR::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

create a serializer with:

```
rails g serializer post
rails g serializer user
```

This will look like

```
class PostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :title
  has_one :user
end
```

In your controller, make sure you're setup:

```
class PostsController 
  respond_to :html, :json
  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    respond_with @post
  end
end
```

Then, you're all set. Make a call to /posts/1.json and you'll get

```
{"post":{"id":1,"title":"the title","user":{"id":1,"name":"jesse"}}}
```